# html word processer buttons

Tags: button, cpu-word, google-docs, bold

I was wondering how to create word processor buttons in html such as:A Bold Button,An Italic button and text size increase button.(THEY DON'T HAVE TO BE PRETTY) any ideas would be GREATLY APPRECIATED! THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve this with HTML alone. This sounds like a job for javascript. What you are looking for is called a rich text box, and there are a few decent open-source options around. You should consider using these before building one from scratch. For instance, WordPress uses TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/ . It is definitely worth a look.